# multiple date periods

Tags: mysql, period

In my MySQL DB I've got one table storing date periods. Each period row has PSTART and PEND columns defining period start and period end dates. How to create a query which will check if one particular date is within any of these periods or not? Number of periods in not fixed!

Comment: Welcome to SO. [What have you tried...?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Better yet, give us an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM periods WHERE [a date] BETWEEN PSTART AND PEND
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question so far, this should give you all rows where date is between `PSTART` and `PEND` - you can modify depending on your requirements for inclusivity/exclusivity:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date>=PSTART AND date<=PEND
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as query before using BETWEEN date1 AND date2

Comment: @sbrbot - First, if you look at the timestamps, I posted my answer before Aknosis' - so it would be incorrect to describe his as 'before' mine. Second, they are not the same, since my answer allows you to control inclusivity/exclusivity of start and end dates.